# JavaScript object array new values

Tags: javascript

This is my first question post :)
I have the following array object:

```
<script>
var tratamentos = {
      "Sr": ["Casado", "Solteiro"],
      "Sra": ["Casada", "Solteira"],}
</script>
```

And I want to add, for example in "Sr" only the values: "Desquitado" and "Enrolado".
Could someone give me some help? I'm racking my brains over this simple thing.

Thanks :)

Comment: `tratamentos.Sr.push('Desquitado')`

Comment: how do you wanna update the value of "Sr", like do you want to add new values?

Comment: `tratamentos["Sr"].push("Desquitado", "Enrolado")`, take a look at [accessing objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#objects_and_properties) and [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can acces items from the nested array using dots (".") and then use .push operator to add items to the array.

```js
var tratamentos = {
      "Sr": ["Casado", "Solteiro"],
      "Sra": ["Casada", "Solteira"],}
tratamentos.Sr.push("Desquitado", "Enrolado");
console.log(tratamentos);
```